# Strange behaviour with Fable to Javascript Bindings

Tags: javascript, fable-f#

I have the following javascript

```
//file1.js

class MyClass {
  constructor(name) {
    this.Name = name;
  }
}

function callMeBack(callback) {
  let v = new MyClass("MyName")
  callback(v)
}

export { callMeBack };
```

and the relative Fable JS bindings

```
//Bindings.fs

type I =
    abstract callMeBack<'t> : callback:('t -> unit) -> unit


module Binding = 
    [<ImportAll("./file1.js")>]
    let mylib: I = jsNative
```

Then I use the bindings in an application, calling javascript twice but with different F# types (class and record)

```
type MyClass(name: string) = 
    let mutable _name: string = name
    member __.Name with get() = _name and set v = _name <- v

type MyRecord = {
    Name: string
} 

let fClass() = 
    Binding.mylib.callMeBack(fun (v:MyClass) ->
        let name = v.Name
        printf "%s" v.Name)

let fRecord() = 
    Binding.mylib.callMeBack(fun (v:MyRecord) ->
        let name = v.Name
        printf "%s" v.Name)
```

Problems:

- Different results between class and record
- With class the result is wrong

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

**Questions**

**1. Why this happens?**

**2. How to obtain the correct result with class type?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binding is not strictly speaking correct - the callback will always receive an instance of the JS class `MyClass`, rather than a generic `'t`.

I believe it should be:

```ml
//Bindings.fs

type IMyClass = interface end

type I =
    abstract callMeBack : callback:(IMyClass -> unit) -> unit


module Binding = 
    [<ImportAll("./file1.js")>]
    let mylib: I = jsNative
```

If you know that the callback always receives an instance with a `Name` property, you can do:

```ml
type IMyClass = 
  abstract Name : string with get
```